# How can Kafka reads be constant irrespective of the datasize?

Tags: apache-kafka

As per the [documentation of Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_constanttime) 
the data structure used in Kafka to store the messages is a simple log where all writes are actually just appends to the log.

What I don't understand here is, many claim that Kafka performance is constant irrespective of the data size it handles.

How can random reads be constant time in a linear data structure?

If I have a single partition topic with 1 billion messages in it. How can the time taken to retrieve the first message be same as the time taken to retrieve the last message, if the reads are always sequential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kafka, the log for each partition is not a single file. It is actually split in segments of fixed size.

For each segment, Kafka knows the start and end offsets. So for a random read, it's easy to find the correct segment.

Then each segment has a couple of indexes (time and offset based). Those are the file named `*.index` and `*.timeindex`. These files enable jumping directly to a location near (or at) the desired read.

So you can see that the total number of segments (also total size of the log) does not really impact the read logic.

Note also that the size of segments, the size of indexes and the index interval are all configurable settings (even at the topic level).